# Initialize state iterating an array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, use-state

This questin will be more clear if i show the code:

initializing state with an empty array is easy:

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
}
```

however, i have an array of paths and i need to create an object for each path like this:

```
{
  source: path,
  options: { type: 'local' }
}
```

**how am i supposed to initialize state with an array of objects which is created using a loop?**

i tried this approach but didnt work:

```
export default function MyComponent({ paths }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState([ paths.map((path) => ({source: path, options: {type: 'local'} }) ]);
}
```

Comment: Don't put [ and ] outside of paths.map, try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use spread operator:

```
export default function MyComponent({ paths }) {
    const [state, setState] = useState([...paths.map((path) => ({source: path, options: { type: 'local' }, }))]);
}
```